# Java 8 Best way to build an IntStream from input

Tags: lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have as input (STDIN)

**0 0 1 2 1**

and I want to create a stream from it the simplest possible way.

I did create a stream by reading one by one each integer and storing them into an ArrayList. From there I just had to use .stream().reduce() to make it work.

What I want is a possible way to create a stream directly from the input

I tried to adapt this code :

```
ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
IntStream is2 = IntStream.generate(inputStream::read).limit(inputStream.available());
```

by using a DataInputStream and the readInt() method

```
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(System.in);
IntStream is2 = IntStream.generate(dis::readInt).limit(5);//later : dis.available() instead of 5
```

but it doesn't work I've incompatible thrown types IOException on the generate function.

Can I do it ? Or is there another way to transform an input into a stream

my reduce function to be applied is

```
reduce( (x , y) -> x ^ y)
```

I've already done this on ArrayList quite easily by doing

```
list.stream().reduce( (x , y) -> x ^ y);
```

**SOLUTION**

I've tried using this with a scanner to do the job but unsuccessfully and now I managed to make it work

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int oi = Stream.of(sc.nextLine().split(" "))
                    .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
                    .reduce( (x , y) -> x ^ y).getAsInt();
    System.out.println(oi);
```

I don't understand why it didn't work at the beginning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int oi = Stream.of(sc.nextLine().split(" "))
                    .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
                    .reduce( (x , y) -> x ^ y).getAsInt();
    System.out.println(oi);
```

Comment: If your input contains lots of numbers, it’s more efficient to use `Pattern.compile(" ").splitAsStream( … )` instead of `Stream.of( … .split(" "))` as the former won’t collect all matches into a temporary array.

Answer (score 0):

Using @Holger recommandation with splitAsStream instead of Stream.of

```
int solution2 = Pattern.compile("\\s+").splitAsStream(sc.nextLine())
                        .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
                        .reduce( (x , y) -> x ^ y).getAsInt();;
    System.out.println(solution2);
```